# Get Order Data using AliExpress Taobao Client API in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sdk

I'm trying to retrieve order details for an item purchased on AliExpress.com using the AliExpress Taobao API. Right now, I'm using [the following code](https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=42707&docType=2):

```
TaobaoClient client = new DefaultTaobaoClient(url, appkey, secret);
AliexpressSolutionOrderInfoGetRequest req = new AliexpressSolutionOrderInfoGetRequest();
OrderDetailQuery obj1 = new OrderDetailQuery();
obj1.setExtInfoBitFlag(11111L);
obj1.setOrderId(12345678L);
req.setParam1(obj1);
AliexpressSolutionOrderInfoGetResponse rsp = client.execute(req, sessionKey);
System.out.println(rsp.getBody());
```

I've downloaded and imported the Java SDK from AliExpress website, however Eclipse still does not recognize the following classes:

```
AliexpressSolutionOrderInfoGetRequest

OrderDetailQuery

AliexpressSolutionOrderInfoGetResponse
```

Which SDK/library should I download for Eclipse to recognize the above three classes? I searched the entire Maven Repository and didn't find anything.

Thanks